# Can't drag folder to desktop

Tags: macos, folders

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion, every time I try to drag a folder to my desktop it only makes an alias. Is there any way to reenable moving regular folders? It's really obnoxious to have to make another directory every time I want to move something for a short while.

Comment: My Mac does not do this, so it is not the standard behaviour. Does pressing alt and cmd while dragging help?

Comment: Holding command makes it drag the actual folder. I want the default behavior though so I don't need an extra command to do what it should do anyhow.

Comment: That is a good interim solution though.

Comment: Did you try log in on as new user ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try deleting the Finder preferences (`rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Finder.plist`)
2. Try to replicate the problem on another user account on the same Mac.
3. Look for utilities which change the keyboard behaviour.